# Why axios not submitting data to asp.core api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, axios

I am trying to send data from React app to my asp.net core API by the help of Axios but not getting the data,

Axios Code

```
    axios.put(urlPath,
                {
                        method: 'put',
                        data: {
 PageDbId: "Soursbh",
            UserDbId:""
}
                    })
                .then(response => onSuccess(response))
                .catch(e => onError(e));
```

Asp Core Model Class

```
public class WebAvatarModel
    {
        public string PageDbId { get; set; }

        public string UserDbId { get; set; }

    }
```

Asp core Code

```
[HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Save_Avatar([FromBody] WebAvatarModel model)
            {
                var users = model;
    
    
                return null;
            }
```

Always getting null in  PageDbId and UserDbId { get; set; }

I also tried this

```
await axios.put(urlPath, JSON.stringify(body),
                {
                    method: 'put',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                })
            .then(response => onSuccess(response))
            .catch(e => onError(e));


 [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Save_Avatar(WebAvatarModel model)
        {
            var users = model;


            return null;
        }
```

But still not working
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you configured the routing right on the .net core ( I don't see the attribute for example HttpPut)

Comment: I only removed the put attribute for testing. it is there but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Always getting null in PageDbId and UserDbId

If you check the actual request payload using browser developer tool, you would find that the data look like below.

[image]

You need to modify your code as below to provide correct request payload.

```
axios.put(urlPath,
    {
        PageDbId: "Soursbh",
        UserDbId: ""
    })
    .then(response => onSuccess(response))
    .catch(e => onError(e));
```

Or

```
axios({
    method: 'put',
    url: urlPath,
    data: {
        PageDbId: "Soursbh",
        UserDbId: ""
    }
})
    .then(response => onSuccess(response))
    .catch(e => onError(e));
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. finally, it's working as I was expected :)

Answer (score 2):

> `public IActionResult Save_Avatar([FromBody] WebAvatarModel model)`

Did this api have `[HttpPut]`?

Comment: Yes I am using put request for updating the data